# Writing Data Exclusion Query in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, symbology, query

I'm currently making a proportional symbol map for ArcMap. Safe to say I'm very bad at building queries. The data I'm using has "0" values in the attribute table. The proportional symbol tab is telling me to "exclude" 0 using the Data Exclusion Properties tab.

However, I have no idea what query I would need to build to make sure the "0" is excluded for both the value field and normalisation field. What would an exclusion query look like?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question and your description of the proportional symbol tab, but if you're trying to set up symbology to show graduated symbols for your features but to exclude those that have an attribute of "0" you can create a definition query (under layer properties) that would be something like:

```
ATTRIBUTE <> 0
```

The <> operator is read as "not equal to" and so after the query only features which have an attribute that isn't 0 would be considered.

Answer (score 1):

In the Symbology tab of the layer properties and in the Proportional Symbols options, you will find a **Data Exclusion** utility, which works as Definition Query as mentioned before but it just does not render the features (for example, info tool still reports the attributes of these invisible features), whereas the latter hinders rendering of the features.

Please see the snapshot below:

[image: s]

In there, say you want to exclude features whose precision is greater than 1000 meters, then you need to input `Precision > 1000`, assuming Precision is the field where the exclusion features will be defined.